# Pytorch mistake demo: Why this RuntimeError occurs the second time when running the backward() line?

Tags: python, pytorch

I write a mistake demo that I know the reason why this error occurs. However, I have no idea why the error occurs the second time in the while loop instead of the first time.

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.w1 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True))
        self.w2 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([3.], requires_grad=True))
        self.w3 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad=True))

    def forward(self, a):
        s = a * self.w1

        c = s * self.w2
        d = s * self.w3

        return c, d


x = torch.tensor([1.])
y1 = torch.tensor([10.])
y2 = torch.tensor([12.])

model = Model()
mse = torch.nn.MSELoss()
# optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.5)
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

num = 0
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)  # For debugging.
while True:
    num += 1
    print(num)
    y1_pred, y2_pred = model(x)
    loss1 = mse(y1_pred, y1)
    loss2 = mse(y2_pred, y2)

    optim.zero_grad()
    loss1.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optim.step()

    optim.zero_grad()
    loss2.backward(retain_graph=True)  # The RuntimeError occurs. But why does it occur in the second iteration in the loop instead of the first iteration?
    optim.step()
```

The error information:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

Pytorch version: 1.9.0

Comment: I think the problem in this case is that you're trying to use the same optimizer for optimizing two separate targets.  Either use two optimizers, or combine the losses into a single loss (e.g. the mean of the two).